# Finding the position of the median of an array containing mostly zeros

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, numpy, indexing, median

I have a very large 1d array with most elements being zero while nonzero elements are all clustered around some few islands separated by many zeros: (here is a smaller version of that for the purpose of a MWE)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,20,14,10,5,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,5,5,18,18,16,14,10,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,6,16,4,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

I want to find the median and its position (even approximately) in terms of the index corresponding to the median value of each island. Not surprisingly, I am getting zero which is not what I desire:

```
In [3]: np.median(A)
Out[3]: 0.0

In [4]: np.argsort(A)[len(A)//2]
Out[4]: 12
```

In the case of a single island of nonzero elements, to work around this caveat and meet my requirement that only nonzero elements are physically meaningful, I remove all zeros first and then take the median of the remaining elements:

```
In [5]: masks = np.where(A>0)
In [6]: A[masks]
Out[6]: array([ 1,  3,  6, 20, 14, 10,  5,  1])
```

This time, I get the median of the new array correctly, however the position (index) would not be correct as it is evident and also pointed out in the comments as being ill-defined mathematically.

```
In [7]: np.median(A[masks])
Out[7]: 5.5

In [8]: np.argsort(A[masks])[len(A[masks])//2]
Out[8]: 2
```

According to this approximation, I know that real median is located in the third index of the modified array but I would like to translate it back into the format of the original array where the position (index) of the median should be somewhere in the middle of the first island of the nonzero elements corresponding to a larger index (where indices of zeros are all counted correctly). Also answered in the comments are two suggestions made to come up with the position of the median given one island of nonzero elements in the middle of a sea of zeros. But what if there is more than one such island? How could possibly one calculate the index corresponding to median of each island in the context of the original histogram array where zeros are all counted?

I am wondering if there is any easy way to calculate the position of the median in such arrays of many zeros. If not, what else should I add to my lines of code to make that possible after knowing the position in the modified array? Your help is great appreciated.

Comment: How about `np.median(masks)`? What's the expected o/p? How about a case where there are more than one *island* of nonzeros?

Comment: Dear Warren, you're right. But I am interested only in the nonzero elements. But the only piece of information I happen to need is to locate this median in the original array with zeros. And I guess Divakar's comment would be considered as an answer.

Comment: Dear Miradulo, that will give me something twice as big as desired.

Comment: That was a great idea that I still need to accomplish Divakar. It is possible to have more than one island is few cases. In those cases, I would need the position of each island. What I know for sure is that any number of these islands will be localized in space.

Comment: So a generalized answer including that caveat of more than one island separated by lots of zeros would be an ideal for my problem.

Comment: The "position" of the median is not a well-defined quantity.  The median of `[3, 8, 9, 7, 2, 1, 9, 7]` is 7, but how would you define its position?

Comment: Consider adding MWE to cover such cases of multiple islands w/ expected o/p.

Comment: Is `A` actually a histogram (i.e. an array of counts), and do you want the median of the values being counted?  Then perhaps something like `np.searchsorted(A.cumsum(), A.sum()/2)` would work.

Comment: That's true Warren, my actual nonzero elements are anywhere from $10^{{-3}}$ to $10^{{7}}$. The good thing about the data is that I know a priori that my statistics are mountain like meaning narrow spike island(s). So, what I will do in those cases is that I should choose the one that is closest to the mean value since I know that my distributions are Gaussian.

Comment: And yes, I would consider this as a second answer since A is actually a discrete histogram with many bins and adding one element to such a big array wouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment "A is actually a discrete histogram with many bins", I think what you want is the median of the values being counted.  If `A` is an integer array of counts, then an exact (but probably very inefficient, if you have values as high as 1e7) formula for the median is

```
np.median(np.repeat(np.arange(len(A)), A))  # Do not use if A contains very large values!
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
np.searchsorted(A.cumsum(), 0.5*A.sum())
```

which will be the integer part of the median.

For example:

```
In [157]: A
Out[157]: 
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  3,
        6, 20, 14, 10,  5,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0])

In [158]: np.median(np.repeat(np.arange(len(A)), A))
Out[158]: 35.5

In [159]: np.searchsorted(A.cumsum(), 0.5*A.sum())
Out[159]: 35
```

Another example:

```
In [167]: B
Out[167]: 
array([  0,   0,   0,   1, 100,  21,   8,   3,   2,   1,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])

In [168]: np.median(np.repeat(np.arange(len(B)), B))
Out[168]: 4.0

In [169]: np.searchsorted(B.cumsum(), 0.5*B.sum())
Out[169]: 4
```

Comment: Thanks dear Warren for your comprehensive answer. I just edited the question so it includes more than one island of nonzero elements. Could you please modify your answer to reflect that?

Comment: That change adds a whole 'nother level of complexity to the problem.  Now you want to identify the "clusters", and compute a median for each cluster.  There isn't a simple modification to my answer that does that.  This answer could be applied to each cluster after you have identified them.  But identifying the clusters should be a new SO question (after you've tried to get it working yourself, of course).